# Why is maven dependency being added automatically to pom when using Eclipse (STS 3.5.1)?

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

The following maven dependency was not added by me (I'm the only dev on the project):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

What is going on here?

Comment: I had a similar case. Even multipe times with different dependencies. Did not find the cause yet. Are you on OSX? Probably kind of shortcut?

Comment: I've also had the problem with multiple dependencies. For example net.wimpi:telnetd-x:2.1.1. I'm on OSX.

Comment: What kind of project did you create in STS?

Comment: If it's "Spring Starter Project" then that's normal. A "Spring Starter Project" uses Spring Boot and that dependency is from Spring Boot.

Comment: @AndreiStefan it's a jersey-spring project. All code is written by hand, except when generating java-classes from XSD using cxf-xjc-plugin.

Comment: Take a look at [this JIRA issue](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3814). Sounds pretty much like your issue. There is an workaround specified there. Give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I'll give the workaround mentioned in the Jira issue a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Workaround per @AndreiStefan from the linked [JIRA issue](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3814):

> Open "Window >> Preferences"
>   Go to "Java >> Editor Content Assist >> Advanced"
>   You will see a 'Jar Type Search' proposal provider. Disable it in both top and bottom.
>   This should disable it across your entire workspace.

Comment: Yes, this seems to have done the trick. The dependency has not come back since I asked the question.